# Define a functional and nest it with its arguments

Tags: functional

I'm looking for a definition of a functional `f` which works correctly with varying arguments `t` while it will be nested.

For example, I've the following code

```
f[g__[t__]] := g[t] + g[t - s]
```

For an input function `in[t]` I'll get

```
f[in[t]]=in[t]+in[t-s]
```

So far so good. But I want to nest the functional like `f[f[in[t]]` and I'm expecting

```
in[t]+2in[t-s]+in[t-2s]
```

as result. But what I get with the above definition is `-s + 2 in[t] + 2 in[-s + t]`. My application is a cascaded FIR digital filter. The output of the first FIR is the input of the next one and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe do something like this:

```
f[ fn_Function ] := (fn[#] + fn[# - s]) &

f[in[#] &][t]
```

> in[t] + in[-s + t]

```
f[f[in[#] &]][t]
```

> in[t] + in[-2 s + t] + 2 in[-s + t]

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your function $f$ does not act on the number $g(t)$, it acts on the function $g$.  I don't have *Mathematica* at hand, but

```
f[g_][t_]:=g[t]+g[t-s];
```

should work.  (Note that you will need to adjust your examples as

```
f[in][t] (*gives in[t]+in[t-s]*)
f[f[in]][t] (*gives in[t]+2in[t-s]+in[t-2s]*)
```

to make them work with this definition.)

Comment: There is a little mistake in your definition. You have swapped the argument `t-s`. But your solution works fine.

Comment: @Drakonomikon Fixed, thanks!